# How to stop sentry server

Tags: sentry

I know how to sentry start.

But when I change the `sentry.conf.py`, how can I make it work?

I run sentry help and can not find sentry stop or restart commond.
Is there a way to restart the sentry server?

Comment: How to you handle sentry start? Manually or using supervisor?

Comment: I kill the sentry server's ppid,and run start commond.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself. I was using supervisor to start my sentry server, and for some reason it was not killing sentry when I stopped supervisor. To fix this, I ran `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 9000` to find the process id that was still running. For me, it was gunicorn. Kill that process then start the server again and your new settings should take effect.

Comment: @Romulus 5 years later and still no stop command :-( https://docs.sentry.io/server/cli/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using systemctl to manage sentry.

Firstly, create an executable file. `run_worker`

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.sentry/bin/activate
SENTRY_CONF=~/sentry sentry run worker>/var/log/sentry_worker.log 2>&1
```

Then, create service files. just like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart={YourPath}/sentry/run_worker
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=0
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Create sentry_web.service sentry_cron.service likewise and use

```
systemctl --user restart sentry_*
```

to restart.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running your workers using supervisor, just run the commands to restart all the workers:

```
supervisorctl
restart all
```

Or if you want to restart single worker enter:

```
supervisorctl
status
```

to get the list of the workers and use:

```
restart worker_name
```

It will restart the sentry process and enable your new configurations.

Comment: You should enter the sentry process name instead of restart all process managed by supervisord